# Is there a reason I shouldn't be testing a set of variables for 0 by testing their product?

Tags: c#, optimization, if-statement

Is there a reason I shouldn't be testing a set of variables for 0 by testing their product?

Often in my coding across different languages I will test a set of variables to do something if they all consist of zeros.

For example (c#):

```
if( myString.Length * myInt * (myUrl.LastIndexOf(@"\")+1) == 0 )
```

Instead of:

```
if( myString.Length == 0 || myInt == 0 || myUrl.LastIndexOf(@"\") < 0)
```

Is there a reason I shouldn't be testing this way?

Comment: I can't think of a legitimate reason why it doesn't work, but the latter is more proper and consistent.

Comment: Uhm, LastIndexOf returns -1 if there is no \ in string.

Comment: Those two code snippets are not equivalent if a \ appears at the beginning of `myUrl`. -- EDIT: He fixed it. See how easy it is to make mistakes if you code like that?

Comment: Or is faster (though by how much so is questionable) and more readable. That simple.

Comment: Side note: any code that contains condition/loop with `+1`/`-1` should require significant time to verify if it is correct when you are looking at the code. If you are not doing it you likely missing large number of one-off errors. (+1 to both answers - code readability is huge thing)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are a few reasons. All are important, and they're in no particular order.

- **Short circuiting**. In your first example, all three things will be evaluated even if they don't need to be. In some cases, this can be a real problem: short circuiting is nice because you can do things like `if (myObj != null && myObj.Enabled)` without throwing exceptions
- **Correctness**. Is `myString.Length * myInt * myUrl.LastIndexOf(@"\") == 0` actually equivalent in all practical cases to `if( myString.Length > 0 && myInt != 0 && myUrl.LastIndexOf(@"\") <= 0)`? I'm not sure. I doubt it. I'm sure I could figure it out with some effort, but why should I have to in the first place? Which brings me to...
- **Clarity**. Since the conventional way is to use separate statements and `&&`, anyone reading this code in the future will have a harder time understanding what it's doing. And don't make the excuse that, "I'll be the only one to read it", because in a few months or years, you'll probably have forgotten the thoughts and conventions you had when you wrote it, and be reading it just like anyone else.

Comment: Ok, I get it. No more obfuscation. I forgot about short circuiting which could be a huge speed boost. I am now a better coder and future devs who look at my code thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't do that because it's not obvious what you're doing. Code should be clean, readable, and easily maintainable.

It's clever, but it's going to make the next person who looks at your code have to "decipher" what your intent was by doing it that way.

Comment: @iambriansreed If you insist, the logical OR version is theoretically faster. Logical OR is faster than mulitplication, and it can short-circuit.

Comment: however, 'no practical difference' depends on what your largest operation is. if it's a mathematical program, it might matter (i had one situation like this where one's a factor of 8 faster). I do concede that for high-level programming it makes no difference.

Comment: @DanielMann It's actually potentially not a micro optimization.  The use of logical operators allows short circuiting.  If one of those operations does something like, say, going to the database to get its value, then being able to skip that check is a *huge* deal.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, you said if there is a difference then it's going to be small; so small you can ignore it.  That's not true.  There are plenty of simple, straighforward, real life examples in which it results in a huge, non-trivial difference in performance.  That's not at all a micro optimization.

Answer (score 1):

There are practical cases in which that will not work.

Consider for example a string of length 65536 where the last character is a "\". `65536 * myInt * 65536` is always zero, because the product contains a factor 2<sup>32</sup> and `int`'s are only 32 bits long. All the bits that would be set are not actually present in the result.

Depending on the value of `myInt`, that can also happen for shorter strings, but a string of 65k isn't *that* much of a stretch. (an URL of 65k may be a bit of a stretch, but whatever)

Note, by the way, that it's not so much the overflow that causes the problem, the problem is having several too-high powers of 2 as factor. For example, if all factors are odd (but high), the result will be odd as well (regardless of overflows), and therefore at least one bit will be set.